# JavaScript: Getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined

I have written a function that takes an array of objects(`students3`) and prints the name of the student and their average test score.

```js
var students3 = [
  {
    name : "Anthony",
    id : 0,
    grades : [{ id : 0, score : 84},{ id : 1, score : 20},{ id : 2, score : 80}]
  }, 
  {
    name : "Winnie",
    id : 1,
    grades : [{ id : 0, score : 62},{ id : 1, score : 56},{ id : 2, score : 100}]
  },
  {
    name : "Pawandeep",
    id : 2,
    grades : [{ id : 0, score : 79},{ id : 1, score : 92},{ id : 2, score : 49}]
  }
];
```

My solution:

```js
function getAverageScore(student)
{
  var sum = 0;
  var grades = student.grades;
  for(var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
  {
    var grade = grades[i];
    sum += grade.score;
  }
  var avg = sum/grades.length;
  return avg;
}


function printAverageGrade(students)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
  {
    var student = students[i];
    var averageScore = getAverageScore(student);

    console.log(student.name, averageScore);
  }
}
```

Expected result after running `console.log(printAverageGrade(students3));` is:

> Anthony 61.333333333333336
>
> Winnie 72.66666666666666
>
> Pawandeep 73.33333333333333

My result:

> Anthony 61.333333333333336
>
> Winnie 72.66666666666666
>
> Pawandeep 73.33333333333333
>
> undefined

**Anyone can tell me why I am getting an undefined value in my result? Thank you.**

Comment: I'm not getting undefined. it seems your code is fine.

Comment: Not getting undefined in latest chrome. Your code looks ok.

Comment: @dinesh https://repl.it/NTdT/0

Comment: @kunjuwang Maybe you are getting undefined because you are running it in a console, because the printAverageGrade() has no return value. If you run it as a html page it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printAverageGrade` function itself itself logs messages to the console. It doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

If you log `printAverageGrade(students3)` to the console, you will log `undefined`.

Solution: don't log `printAverageGrade(students3)`:

`console.log(printAverageGrade(students3))` → `printAverageGrade(students3)`

Answer (score 1):

That last line is the return value of the function. If you look at the `getAverageScore(student)` function, you can see that you `return avg;`, which is what gives that value.

`printAverageGrades` doesn't return anything, so its return value is `undefined`. The console logging works though, so as long as you don't try to use it to set any variables, this code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from your browser's JavaScript console, are you sure you're not seeing the return value of `printAverageGrade`? See this simple example:

```
> function foo() { console.log("hello"); }
<- undefined
> foo()
  hello
<- undefined
```

The two `undefined` are from the console trying to print the return value of the immediate command, and if we try this instead:

```
> function foo() { console.log("hello"); return "defined"; }
<- undefined
> foo()
  hello
<- "defined"
```

---

Specifically, your sample code uses:

```
console.log(printAverageGrade(students3));
```

Since `printAverageGrade()` returns nothing, the console logs `undefined`.